# One Service Two Repo

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Title as shown below.  The problem is when I call EDIRepoName.findById(shortName) I get an error that implies it is using the wrong repo.  (I will guarantee the shortName is unique, but I need to lookup by it.)

> Wed May 27 09:43:49 EDT 2020 There was an unexpected error
>   (type=Internal Server Error, status=500). Provided id of the wrong
>   type for class com.example.ta_edi.model.EDIType. Expected: class
>   java.lang.Long, got class java.lang.String; nested exception

```
public class EDITypeService {
    @Autowired
    EDITypeRepository ediRepo;
    @Autowired
    EDITypeNameRepository ediRepoName;

public interface EDITypeRepository extends CrudRepository<EDIType,Long> {   

}

public interface EDITypeNameRepository extends CrudRepository<EDIType,String> {
}



public Optional<EDIType> getByShort(EDIType ediType) {
        //dangerous.assume shortName is unique.
        String shortName = ediType.getShortName();
        Optional<EDIType> found = ediRepoName.findById(shortName);
        return found; 
    }
```

Updated:
Can I not have a repository that does a lookup on a non-primary key? If so that would explain the error.  Then how do I lookup by other than a primary key?

```
@Entity
public class EDIType {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long index;
    @CreationTimestamp
    LocalDateTime created;
    @UpdateTimestamp
    LocalDateTime updated;
    String shortName; 
    String processType; 
    @Lob
    Clob xmlFile;
```

Thank you, but I did this modification first below and got the error second below

```
public interface EDITypeNameRepository extends CrudRepository<EDIType,String> {     
    @Query("SELECT p FROM EDIType WHERE LOWER(p.shortName)=LOWER(:shortName)")
        public List<EDIType> byShortName(@Param("shortName") String shortName);

}
```

> Error creating bean with name 'EDITypeNameRepository': FactoryBean
>   threw exception on object creation; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for
>   method public abstract java.util.List
>   com.example.ta_edi.repository.EDITypeNameRepository.byShortName(java.lang.String)!

Comment: Your EDIType either has Long or String as ID. You can't have both. What are you trying to accomplish with these two Repositories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need two repositories for searching by shortName.
Just add `findByShortName` method to `EDITypeRepository`

```
public interface EDITypeRepository extends CrudRepository<EDIType,Long> {   
     Optional<EDIType> findOneByShortName(String name) 
}
```

It would be enough for your issue

Comment: But, but, it is like magic;)  If you have a minute why didnt my attempt at a JPA query work?  It tried it with the "value" to prevent validation.  Does the CrudRepository create a method for every elements of the class?  Thank you again.

Comment: Your attempt didn't worked cause of incorrect Repository at all. The id of your entity is long, but you tried no create repository for string-based entity. 
You should check spring manual about how CrudRepository works
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#project

Answer (score 1):

Show the source code of `EDIType`. Looks like problem is there - your entity has `Long` id but not `String`

So your id is Long. Just add findByShortName method to correct repository and call it.